# Angular2 : passing property to nested component

Tags: angular

I am developing a simple test app in Angular 2 and having problems passing a property to a nested component.  See source code below.  The template from the nested component renders, but the property passed to the nested component does not render.  The rendered output is:

This is a .

Whereas, I would expect the following:

This is a test.

No errors are generated in the browser console. I have also tried utilizing `properties: 'inputtext'` in the nested component since the name remains the same in the view, but this generates a *Can't bind to ...* error in the console.   As for the Angular2 version, I'm using the latest (Alpha-34).

Any suggestions?

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 Test App</title>
    <script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.34/angular2.dev.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to my Angular 2 Test App</h1>
    <app></app>
    <script>System.import('app');</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.ts**

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

//nested component
@Component({
  selector: 'input-component',
  properties: ['inputtext:inputtext']
})
@View({ template: '<h1>This is a {{inputtext}}.</h1>'})
class inputComponent{}

// root app
@Component({ selector: 'app' })
@View({ 
  directives: [inputComponent], 
  template: '<input-component [inputtext]="test"></input-component>' 
})
class rootApp{}

bootstrap(rootApp);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because you don't bind a variable on your property, you just pass it a literal value. In that case you need to drop the squared brackets and give it like this : inputtext="test". If you use the squared brackets angular2 will expect a variable and will try to map to it, which will give you undefined.

Also note that when you define a property if the variable in your controller has the same name as the property you expose you can use the short form :

```
properties: ['inputtext']
```

Comment: still no real documentation on `properties`.  this was a real help!

Answer (score 2):

```
template: '<input-component [inputtext]="\'test\'"></input-component>'
```

test in your code is an undefined variable. Wrap it with quotes and it should work.

Comment: This results in the error: 'Can't bind to 'inputtext' since it isn't a known property of 'input-component'